# splash screen not work with navigation drawer

Tags: navigation, drawer, splash-screen

navigation drawer is working perfect but when i added splash screen to my project it not work

splasScreen

[image]

manifest

[image]

Comment: Please add the code directly to your post, not just a screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

It took me a while for me to solve this too.

Your Main Activity in Android Manifest should look like this

Activity Section On Android Manifest should look like this:
[**Note the MainActive Theme**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjL8c.png)

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ayo you saved my hours:)

Comment: Thanks.this helped me nd saved my time too

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.nulledapps.website2app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        Thread mythraed = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(3000);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        mythraed.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nulledapps.website2app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is work for me, try it :D

### SplashScreen.java code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(3000);
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

}

### AndroidManiffest.xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="TEST"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="TEST"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
</application>
```